# groups in regular expression out of range

Tags: python, regex, pandas

```
time_sentences = ["Monday: The doctor's appointment is at 2:45pm.", 
                  "Tuesday: The dentist's appointment is at 11:30 am.",
                  "Wednesday: At 7:00pm, there is a basketball game!",
                  "Thursday: Be back home by 11:15 pm at the latest.",
                  "Friday: Take the train at 08:10 am, arrive at 09:00am."]

df['text'].str.replace(r'(\w+day\b)', lambda x: x.group(0)[:3])
```

Notice above we have one group, so we are accessing that group with 0.

I am expecting if we pass 1 for group we should get error as out of range like no such group but we are not getting that error.

```
df['text'].str.replace(r'(\w+day\b)', lambda x: x.group(1)[:3])
```

If we pass 2 for group then we are getting out of range error.

```
df['text'].str.replace(r'(\w+day\b)', lambda x: x.group(2)[:3])
```

Any reason why?

Comment: The number of `group()`s is equal to the number of pairs of unescaped parentheses `(...)` in the pattern. The `r'(\w+day\b)'` pattern only contains 1 capturing group, so `group(1)` works well when there is a match, `group(2)` will throw an exception even if there is a match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `()` capturing group stores the captured characters inside the first group index. `.group()` or `.group(0)` should return all the matched characters where as the index 1 or n returns all the characters captured by the corresponding capturing group 1 or n.

Remove those `()` capturing group from the regex , it should throw error on accessing `x.group(1)`

Comment: Thanks for clarification